# The type of options(Object...) is erroneous, Telerivet API

Tags: java, error-handling, compiler-errors

I would like to test Telerivet API and have the following code:

```
TelerivetAPI tr = new TelerivetAPI(YOUR_API_KEY);
Project project = tr.initProjectById(project_id);

Message sent_msg = project.sendMessage(Util.options(
"content", "hello world", 
"to_number", "+16505550123"
));
```

The error I am getting is on `.options(..)`, it says `The type of options(Object...) is erroneous`. How to solve that? thanks.